# Jmeter | reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-max-priority' for queue

Tags: jmeter, rabbitmq, priority-queue, amqp, jmeter-plugins

I'm getting below error while pushing a message to queue.

`Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-max-priority' for queue '9818627299-whatsapp_self_serve-webhook' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value '10' of type 'signedint', class-id=50, method-id=10) at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:517) ~[amqp-client-5.16.0.jar:5.16.0] at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:341) ~[amqp-client-5.16.0.jar:5.16.0] at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:182) ~[amqp-client-5.16.0.jar:5.16.0] at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:114) ~[amqp-client-5.16.0.jar:5.16.0] at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:739) ~[amqp-client-5.16.0.jar:5.16.0] at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47) ~[amqp-client-5.16.0.jar:5.16.0] at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:666) ~[amqp-client-5.16.0.jar:5.16.0]`

Queue is having x-max-priority feature as shown in the image.
[RMQ UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O2Lv.png)

I'm using AMQP publisher in Jmeter to push message onto queue.

I just understood, maybe it needs x-max-priority value as PRE-CONDITION before pushing any messages onto queue but, I'm not sure where can I mention that on UI.

On UI we've other parameter on UI like Durable, Auto Delete, etc...but, couldn't find a way to add x-max-priority.

Please let me know if I'm missing anything here or is there any other way to do this in jmeter.

Thanks in advance!